# Intellij is not running individual Spock tests in Grails any more

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, spock

My company switched from idea-131 to idea-171 a few months back (which I've been keeping updated ever since). One thing I've noticed is that I can no longer run Spock unit tests individually anymore. Instead, when I right click on a test, it only offers me the ability to run the whole file.  That's kind of annoying if a page has 40 tests! Is there a config somewhere that I need to tick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I answered that question as soon as i asked it! they've moved the option to a little play button headed beside each test method. I'm not a fan of iconicizing little commands but ... there you go.

Comment: You can accept your own answer so that other can see that it is solved.

Comment: Yeah, I tried, SO is grumbling at me to wait until 2 days have passed before I can do that XD ho hum!